# Remove stdclass object from array second time always fails

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, stdclass

Can you please help me find a problem in my code. I have a function for deleting images from my json string. I will provide my code with explanation.

This is my test controller for testing my code

```
<?php class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Model_products');
    }

    public function index(){
        echo 'This is test controller';

        $id_product = 1;
        $id_image = 3;
        $prod = $this->Model_products->getCurrentUserProduct($id_product);
        $images = json_decode($prod[0]->images);
        var_dump($images);
        foreach($images as $i){
            if($i->id_image == $id_image){
                unset($images[$i->id_image]);
            }
        }
        $n = 0;
        foreach($images as $i){
            $i->id_image = $n;
            $i->position = $n;
            $n++;
        }
        var_dump($images);
        $this->Model_products->updateProductImages($id_product, json_encode($images));
        die();
    }
}
```

First var_dump($images) output is

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'id_image' => int 0
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/f81e86620f557fa9fc5e71d063c12d6a.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string 'f81e86620f557fa9fc5e71d063c12d6a.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/2b6cfd74e622c4a61793259438b90b39.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string '2b6cfd74e622c4a61793259438b90b39.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 0
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'id_image' => int 1
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/458270b1c351bf23a4c943ae9b393eb5.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '458270b1c351bf23a4c943ae9b393eb5.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/425a2346219aca49e0c1048da14d6276.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string '425a2346219aca49e0c1048da14d6276.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 1
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'id_image' => int 2
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/11bbe81edace48a1d6e03159c72bfc7f.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '11bbe81edace48a1d6e03159c72bfc7f.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/a0d9059a611d49ea84c1e57c683b643b.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'a0d9059a611d49ea84c1e57c683b643b.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 2
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'id_image' => int 3
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/0702f21fc6f7773aa5f44f4115241a35.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '0702f21fc6f7773aa5f44f4115241a35.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/d9dfb48ddee4a20e35cb433619f0da0b.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'd9dfb48ddee4a20e35cb433619f0da0b.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 3
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'id_image' => int 4
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/32e902b9e64758f4dca64039833cbf0a.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '32e902b9e64758f4dca64039833cbf0a.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/e31eaac5e991baf862d2ecc264145642.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'e31eaac5e991baf862d2ecc264145642.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 4
```

which is correct, since my product has 5 images

Now i loop through $images and i wan't to delete array object, where $id_image = 3.
So this is second var_dump($images) output which is in my opinion correct, since in my code i remove one array and "reset" id of images and positions

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[24]
      public 'id_image' => int 0
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/f81e86620f557fa9fc5e71d063c12d6a.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string 'f81e86620f557fa9fc5e71d063c12d6a.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/2b6cfd74e622c4a61793259438b90b39.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string '2b6cfd74e622c4a61793259438b90b39.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 0
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'id_image' => int 1
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/458270b1c351bf23a4c943ae9b393eb5.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '458270b1c351bf23a4c943ae9b393eb5.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/425a2346219aca49e0c1048da14d6276.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string '425a2346219aca49e0c1048da14d6276.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 1
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'id_image' => int 2
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/11bbe81edace48a1d6e03159c72bfc7f.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '11bbe81edace48a1d6e03159c72bfc7f.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/a0d9059a611d49ea84c1e57c683b643b.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'a0d9059a611d49ea84c1e57c683b643b.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 2
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'id_image' => int 3
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/32e902b9e64758f4dca64039833cbf0a.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '32e902b9e64758f4dca64039833cbf0a.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/e31eaac5e991baf862d2ecc264145642.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'e31eaac5e991baf862d2ecc264145642.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 3
```

So problem happens now, if i try to return this code again (just pressing F5)
I get the output from first var_dump($images)

```
object(stdClass)[24]
  public '0' => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'id_image' => int 0
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/f81e86620f557fa9fc5e71d063c12d6a.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string 'f81e86620f557fa9fc5e71d063c12d6a.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/2b6cfd74e622c4a61793259438b90b39.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string '2b6cfd74e622c4a61793259438b90b39.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 0
  public '1' => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'id_image' => int 1
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/458270b1c351bf23a4c943ae9b393eb5.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '458270b1c351bf23a4c943ae9b393eb5.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/425a2346219aca49e0c1048da14d6276.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string '425a2346219aca49e0c1048da14d6276.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 1
  public '2' => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'id_image' => int 2
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/11bbe81edace48a1d6e03159c72bfc7f.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '11bbe81edace48a1d6e03159c72bfc7f.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/a0d9059a611d49ea84c1e57c683b643b.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'a0d9059a611d49ea84c1e57c683b643b.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 2
  public '4' => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'id_image' => int 3
      public 'thumbImage' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/32e902b9e64758f4dca64039833cbf0a.jpg' (length=102)
      public 'thumbName' => string '32e902b9e64758f4dca64039833cbf0a.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'image' => string '/home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/images/products/large/e31eaac5e991baf862d2ecc264145642.jpg' (length=108)
      public 'imageName' => string 'e31eaac5e991baf862d2ecc264145642.jpg' (length=36)
      public 'position' => int 3
```

**And the following error**

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/valor/development/euro-swap.com/public_html/server/application/controllers/Test.php on line 18
```

What is happening? Why code always works for first time, but always fails each next time?
If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide.

Comment: You don't have an array the second time, but an object `object(stdClass)[24]` Something weird must happen in your model

Comment: nice eyes! Probably i'm storing images wrong way. I'm researching further

Comment: Didn't you unset one element in `unset($images[$i->id_image]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
json_decode($yourJson,true);
```

for force return associative array

Comment: Good job! That saved me a lot of work, because i was in middle of rewriting whole function.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use object ( $object->property )   as   $object['property']

But this is object and syntax is $obj->property

And array is   $array['offset']

Or use $query->result_array() instead $query->result()

And return in a model method query object, this more convenient

Comment: stdClass return by json_decode function... Because I click down 1

Comment: yes in model, there is already written $query->result_array(), but json_decode function automatically returns stdClass object, so i needed to use son_decode($yourJson,true);